# How to deploy angular 5 app with PHP as backend and MySQL as database to AWS

Tags: php, mysql, angular

I have developed a **angular app** using **PHP** as back-end and **MySQL** database. Now, I need to deploy this application to **AWS**.

Up to my knowledge I will do a **ng-build --prod** so that I will get a **DIST** folder and along with it will deploy the **PHP** folder where my php files are there to the server.

Does this work or I missed anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to do as I stated above. Just do a ng-build --prod and generate the DIST folder.

Connect to whatever server you need to upload the files using any applicatons depending on the OS your using and upload the DIST folder files along with any backend code files needed like PHP files or any other if required.

And don't forget to create a database in the server to communicate with the backend if required.

Answer (score 0):

Build scripts like ng-build produce minified production ready code they don't handle anything to do with deployment.

You will need to deploy an aws instance setup a webserver stack and deploy your code, but there is too much scope on both the aws deployment and code deployment for this question to be relevent